# How can I efficiently compute the SHA1 sums of a bunch of chunks of a file from the command line?

Tags: bash, sha1

I have a file f on which I want to compute a sequence of SHA1 hashes, one for each 2 kB chunk of the file. For example, if f is 1G in size, I want to compute roughly 500 thousand hashes: one each for bytes 0-2047, bytes 2048-4095, bytes 4096-6143, bytes 6144-8192, and so on. Ideally I'd like to do this all with one pass reading over the file and stream the results into another file or pipe. I know about the `split` and `sha1sum` commands, but I'm not sure how I might be able to combine these with other commands to achieve this goal. Is there something like `split` that would avoid creating intermediate files and be useful for computing these SHA1 sums?

If I were implementing this at a lower level I would of course just sequentially read the file into a small buffer from which I would compute the SHA1 sums before reusing the buffer for each new chunk, but I'd prefer a simple bash one-liner if there is one. Is there a good way to do this in bash (assume f can contain null bytes)?

Comment: Can the file contain null bytes? (I'm guessing the answer is "yes", but am asking on the off-chance that it's "no". For the reasons noted [in this unix.stackexchange.com question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174016/12378), your options are a bit more limited if the file can contain null bytes.)

Comment: I know how it [could be done easily using Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).  So if a little Python embedded in your Bash script would be acceptable for you…

Comment: Yes, added a clarification at the end of the question.

Comment: @5gon12eder, A simple python solution would be interesting but I guess it would be much slower than a solution that has `sha1sum` as a bottleneck.

Comment: I don't think that the Python solution would be much slower.  The computationally expensive parts will be done in C code anyway.

Comment: I guess it might be reasonable, the only concern is it would be nice to be able to produce these hash sequences from an effortlessly copy-pasted one-liner to a remote machine that doesn't have lots of things installed on it without scp-ing a file or copy-pasting a larger section of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using [Python's `hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).  It is small enough to reasonably inline in a shell script.

```py
#!/bin/bash -eu

python <<EOF
import hashlib

chunksize = 2048
md = hashlib.sha1()
with open("$1", 'rb') as istr:
    while True:
        chunk = istr.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        md.update(chunk)
        print(md.hexdigest())
EOF
```

I have timed it using a 1 GiB file stored in a ramdisk.  The `sha1sum` command line tool took 3.24 seconds to hash the entire file.  The above script took (with standard output piped to `/dev/null`) 7.35 seconds which is about twice as long.  This looks pretty good to me, especially if one takes into account that it actually does more work.

Note that this computes cumulative hashes (each digests covers all previous bytes).  After reading the other answer, I'm not so sure any more if this is what you wanted.  If you want independent digests, you'll have to move the `md = hashlib.sha1()` inside the loop.  The above benchmark takes 8.26 s in this case.

Comment: + 1 both for the general approach, and for the timing comparisons, though the specific code is not quite right, in that it emits *cumulative* digests (one for the first 2KB, one for the first 4KB, etc.), which is not what the OP wants. (Also, isn't `md` for MD5?)

Comment: I thought the OP wanted this but I have already added a comment to my answer.  It's not a big thing to change.  In my slang at least, “md” stands for “message digest” which is just a generic word for “hash”.

Comment: Re: "it's not a big thing to change": True, but it might affect the timing? Not sure. Re: "'md' stands for 'message digest'": Oh, duh, O.K.

Answer (score 1):

So, this approach works on a machine I have handy:

```
(
  file=large-file.txt
  size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
  for (( i = 0 ; i * 2048 < size ; ++i )) ; do
    head -c 2k | sha1sum -
  done < "$file"
)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
( file=large-file.txt ; size=$(stat -c %s "$file") ; for (( i = 0 ; i * 2048 < size ; ++i )) ; do ; head -c 2k | sha1sum - ; done < "$file" )
```

On my machine, each iteration of the for-loop reads just the first 2KB and passes them to `sha1sum`, leaving the rest of the file for the next iteration.

However, I don't see anything in the documentation for `head` that *promises* this behavior. (`head -c 2k` is documented to only print 2 kilobytes, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it will only consume 2 kilobytes from standard input.) So although it works on at least one box, I can't promise that it's portable to all boxes you might want to use it on. (And for that matter, the `-c` flag itself is not specified by POSIX; rather, it's a feature of the GNU implementation.)

Comment: If you want something which is posix standard and guaranteed to read exactly 2kb and no more, use `dd count=1 bs=2k`. (Posix specifies that `k` is 1024.)